# Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gdal, shapefile, jupyter-lab

I am not able to read the shape file. It says no such working directory.
[image]

```
!pip install sentinelsat
!pip install geopandas
!pip install folium
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI
user = '****' 
password = '****' 
api = SentinelAPI(user, password, 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
import geopandas as gpd
import folium 

nReserve = gpd.read_file(r"G:\New folder (2)\cardinialres.shp")

m = folium.Map([-37.971389,  145.418889], zoom_start=12)
folium.GeoJson(nReserve).add_to(m)
m
```

''I googled and found that I need to use `SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX=YES fio info myshapefile.shp` but do not know where to use in Jupiter lab.

Answer (score 39):

All the file which come with .shp file should be in same folder (.shx, .prj, .dbf)

Comment: True, but the issue can arise when the .shx file is corrupted, not when it is missing.  Nothing to do with not having all the shapefile files in a folder.

Answer (score 5):

Fix this issue, after a little more understanding of the .shp objects.
The solution is to have all other relevant files that come along with .shp file in one folder!

if you working with the river dataset
Ex.
`river.shp`
`river.prj`
`river.dbf`
`river.shx`

Comment: So, your files are all in zip format? gpd.read_file(r"path_to_file.zip")?

Answer (score 5):

set GDAL config like this and it will create missing SHX

```
from osgeo import gdal
import geopandas as gpd
gdal.SetConfigOption('SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX', 'YES')
in_vector = '/Users/adi/projects/cds_scrap/f6089a8c/f6089a8c.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(in_vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when using `pyogrio` you can set GDAL config options like so

```py
from pyogrio import set_gdal_config_options

set_gdal_config_options({
    'SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX': 'YES',
})
```